# How to load Excel raw data into power query without converting into data table?

Tags: excel, powerquery

I am trying to find the name and full path of the current excel file where the power query is run.
I dont need the filename as such, its just that I want to have access to a sheet which do not have any data table, rather raw data is there.

When I try the `Excel.CurrentWorkbook()` it only gives a list of tables in the current workbook. But when I try to access the file using its name and full path using `File.Contents()` then all the sheet objects are returned which includes the sheets that contain raw data (without being converted into a data table).

So my plan is, if I could get the file name and path of the current workbook, then I can use it to access the sheet. I cant hardcode the file name as it gets changed everyday with the date as suffix.

Is there any other way around it?

Comment: If the filename of path doesn‘t change often, you can use a parameter. 
However I use the CELL() Version as Alexis discribed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is currently possible using `Excel.CurrentWorkbook()`.

It's possible to use a substring of `CELL("filename")` as a named range to read in the current path and workbook name into Power Query to use `File.Contents` but at that point, it's probably easier just to convert the sheet to a named range instead (only a few keys/clicks: select all data and hit the From Table button in the Data tab Get & Transform ribbon section).